# Anchor tags/link in a div that appears on click do not function

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, anchor, hidden

I am having an issue where the anchor tags/links in #container_x (which appears when clicking .menu using JQuery .toggle) do not work.

Here is the web page where I am having this problem. You can see #container_x by clicking on the eye graphic in the upper right of the page. It will be most useful to view the source of the page, but I posted the relevant code as well:
http://unitest02.businesscatalyst.com/index.html#container_one

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

//opens container_X
  $('.menu').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});

//closes container_X and is located inside container_x 
$('.menu_x').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.a').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.b').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.c').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.d').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.e').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});
$('.f').click(function() {
  $('#container_x').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.

  });
});

  });
```

```css
#container_x
{
   height: 250%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0%;
  /* margin-top: -50%;*/
 background: url(images/menubkg.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  z-index: 400; 
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    data-offset-top:"121";
     data-spy: "affix";

}
.menu_x{
    display: inline-block;
    position:  absolute;
    left: 87%;
    width: 12%;
    top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index: 500;
}

.menu_titles{
 zoom: 0.60;
   z-index: 450; 
}
.menu{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 87%;
    width: 12%;
    top: 0px;
    padding:0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_x">

<a href="#" onClick="close()"><img class="menu_x" src="images/menu_open.png" onmouseover="src='images/menu_eye.gif';" onmouseout="src='images/menu_open.png';"></a> 
    <div class="menu_titles">

        <center>
            <br> <br><br> <br><br> <br>
        <a herf="#container_one"><img class="a" style="height: 12%; width: auto;" src="images/about.png" onmouseover="src='images/abouthov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/about.png';"></a> <br>
        <a herf="/resume.html"><img class="b"  style="height: 12%;" src="images/resume.png" onmouseover="src='images/resumehov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/resume.png';"></a> <br>
        <a herf="#container_two"><img class="c"  style="height: 12%;" src="images/games.png" onmouseover="src='images/gameshov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/games.png';"></a> <br>
        <a herf="#container_four"><img class="d"  style="height: 12%;" src="images/comic.png" onmouseover="src='images/comichov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/comic.png';"></a> <br>
        <a herf="#container_five"><img class="e"  style="height: 12%;" src="images/fellatia.png" onmouseover="src='images/fellatiahov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/fellatia.png';"></a> <br>
        <a herf="#container_seven"><img class="f"  style="height: 12%;" src="images/shop.png" onmouseover="src='images/shophov.png';" onmouseout="src='images/shop.png';"></a> <br>
        </center>


    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would of appreciated a warning that the site is NSFW.

Comment: center tags are obsolete use margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto

Comment: and learn how to spell href